# Formatting Sandbox

Tags: support, formatting

If [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/3122/351462), [Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/269754/3357935), [Super User](https://meta.superuser.com/q/5930/358766), [Arqade](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/716/181240), [Code Golf](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2140/65907), and [Mathematics](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/370/440070) can all have their own sandboxes, why not let *Movies & TV* join the fun as well?

**[The usual sandbox guidelines apply here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/3122/351462). Use this post as a formatting sandbox by posting answers or comments below.**

---

<sup>*Meta Stack Exchange [technically](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox) [has](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51812/the-api-sandbox) [four](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239456/stack-snippets-sandbox-try-it-out-here) [sandboxes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/194835/sandbox-for-android-app), but who's counting?</sup>

Answer (score 4):

## Testing YouTube URL Embedding

**Regular** `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gocwRvLhDf8`

---

**Shortened** `https://youtu.be/gocwRvLhDf8`

---

**Timestamped (Shortened)** `https://youtu.be/gocwRvLhDf8?t=22`

---

**Timestamped (&t=##)** `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gocwRvLhDf8&t=22`

---

**Timestamped (&t=#m##s)** `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gocwRvLhDf8&t=0m22s`

---

**Timestamped (&start=##)** `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gocwRvLhDf8&start=22`

---

**Timestamped (#t=#m##s)** `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gocwRvLhDf8#t=0m22s`

<sup>(Spoiler: This one doesn't work, the video plays from the beginning.)</sup>

---

**/Embed** `https://www.youtube.com/embed/gocwRvLhDf8`

https://www.youtube.com/embed/gocwRvLhDf8

---

**Embedded HTML** `<iframe width="854" height="480" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/gocwRvLhDf8" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>`

---

**Mobile** `https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=gocwRvLhDf8`

---

**Flash Player** `https://www.youtube.com/v/gocwRvLhDf8`

https://www.youtube.com/v/gocwRvLhDf8

---

**YouTube TV** `https://www.youtube.com/tv#/watch/video/idle?v=gocwRvLhDf8`

https://www.youtube.com/tv#/watch/video/idle?v=gocwRvLhDf8

---

**Unencrypted HTTP** `http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gocwRvLhDf8`

---

### Testing YouTube URL placement

**Middle of paragraph:** `Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gocwRvLhDf8 consectetur adipiscing elit`

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet

consectetur adipiscing elit

---

**In block quote:** `> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gocwRvLhDf8`

> 

---

**In bulleted list:** `* https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gocwRvLhDf8`

- 

---

**Inside <kbd> tags:** `<kbd>foo https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gocwRvLhDf8 bar</kbd>`

foo

bar

<sup>(Note: Looks like this produces invalid HTML; rendering may vary between browsers.)</sup>

---

### Testing link syntax variations

**[link](URL):** `[foo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gocwRvLhDf8)`

[foo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gocwRvLhDf8)

---

**[URL](URL):** `[https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gocwRvLhDf8](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gocwRvLhDf8)`

---

**[URL](alt.URL):** `[https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gocwRvLhDf8](https://youtu.be/gocwRvLhDf8)`

[https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gocwRvLhDf8](https://youtu.be/gocwRvLhDf8)

---

**[URL](URL "title"):** `[https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gocwRvLhDf8](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gocwRvLhDf8 "Link title")`

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gocwRvLhDf8

Answer (score 2):

## Testing Spoilers

> spoiler

new line

> ! spoiler line 1
>
> ! spoiler line 2 (return twice, `>!` prefix)

new line

> ! spoiler line 1
>   spoiler line 2 (return once, no `>!` prefix)

new line

> ! spoiler line 1
>   
> spoiler line 2 (return once, `<br>` prefix)

new line

> spoiler line 1
> spoiler line 2 (no return, `<br>` prefix)

new line

> quote line 1
>
> ! spoiler line 2 (return twice, `>!` prefix)

new line

> ! spoiler line 1
>
> quote line 2 (return twice, `>` prefix)

new line

> > quote with nested spoiler

new line

> > spoiler with nested quote

Comment: > quote in comment

Comment: >! spoiler in comment

Comment: ^ never really expected them to work

Answer (score 1):

Keybord made using HTML and `&nbsp;` originally from [Anime and Manga.SE](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/a/873/1587)

[image: Keyboard]

<kbd>Esc</kbd>  <kbd>F1</kbd><kbd>F2</kbd><kbd>F3</kbd><kbd>F4</kbd>  <kbd>F5</kbd><kbd>F6</kbd><kbd>F7</kbd><kbd>F8</kbd>   <kbd>F9</kbd><kbd>F10</kbd><kbd>F11</kbd><kbd>F12</kbd>
<kbd><sub>`</sub><sup>~</sup></kbd>   <kbd><sub>1</sub><sup>!</sup></kbd><kbd><sub>2</sub><sup>@</sup></kbd><kbd><sub>3</sub><sup>#</sup></kbd><kbd><sub>4</sub><sup>$</sup></kbd><kbd><sub>5</sub><sup>%</sup></kbd><kbd><sub>6</sub><sup>^</sup></kbd><kbd><sub>7</sub><sup>&</sup></kbd><kbd><sub>8</sub><sup>*</sup></kbd><kbd><sub>9</sub><sup>(</sup></kbd><kbd><sub>0</sub><sup>)</sup></kbd><kbd><sub>-</sub><sup>_</sup></kbd><kbd><sub>=</sub><sup>+</sup></kbd><kbd><- Backspace</kbd>
<kbd>Tab</kbd>    <kbd>Q</kbd>  <kbd>W</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> <kbd>R</kbd>  <kbd>T</kbd> <kbd>Y</kbd> <kbd>U</kbd> <kbd>I</kbd> <kbd>O</kbd> <kbd>P</kbd><kbd><sub>[</sub><sup>{</sup></kbd><kbd><sub>]</sub><sup>}</sup></kbd><kbd><sub>\</sub><sup>|</sup></kbd>                 
<kbd>Caps Lock</kbd><kbd>A</kbd><kbd>S</kbd><kbd>D</kbd><kbd>F</kbd> <kbd>G</kbd> <kbd>H</kbd> <kbd>J</kbd> <kbd>K</kbd> <kbd>L</kbd> <kbd><sub>;</sub><sup>:</sup></kbd><kbd><sub>'</sub><sup>"</sup></kbd><kbd>↵ Enter</kbd>            
<kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd>           <kbd>Z</kbd><kbd>X</kbd><kbd>C</kbd><kbd>V</kbd><kbd>B</kbd> <kbd>N</kbd> <kbd>M</kbd> <kbd><sub>,</sub><sup><</sup></kbd><kbd><sub>.</sub><sup>></sup></kbd><kbd><sub>/</sub><sup>?</sup></kbd><kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd>                  

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>         <kbd>Win</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd>                                           <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Win</kbd><kbd>????</kbd>     <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>

Comment: <kbd><sub>1</sub><sup>!</sup></kbd>

Answer (score 1):

[Image Sizing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74312/thumbnail-image-on-stack-overflow/108821) - Same image, different suffix.

Full Size

`https://i.stack.imgur.com/ewgpv.png`

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ewgpv.png]

Medium Size

`https://i.stack.imgur.com/ewgpvm.png`

[image]

Thumbnail

`https://i.stack.imgur.com/ewgpvt.png`

[image]

Small (Will crop)

`https://i.stack.imgur.com/ewgpvs.png`

[image]

Or just use old HTML method:

```
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/ewgpv.png" width="150" height="150">
```

[image]